# wp_get_attachment_image: Best way to fill the 'sizes' attribute manually?

Tags: wordpress

When using the wp_get_attachment_image() function in WordPress, by default it outputs a value in the 'sizes' attribute of the img tag. This sizes attribute tells the browser which thumbnail size of the image to load.

The value seems to be related to the largest image in the srcset attribute. So:

- an image with dimensions of 2509x1673 gets: `sizes="(max-width: 2509px) 100vw, 2509px"`
- an image with dimensions of 768x512 gets: `sizes="(max-width: 768px) 100vw, 768px"`

But this only works right when the image is being displayed over the full width of the browser window. If the image is shown in one column of a grid, the browser should be loading a much smaller version of the image.

So I overwrite the sizes attribute like this:

`echo wp_get_attachment_image( $term_image, $term_image_size, false, array('sizes' => '(max-width: 575px) 258px, (max-width: 991px) 330px, 436px'));`

But this feels like an absolute hassle. I understand that the server and/or WordPress are not able to decide what the sizes attribute needs to contain upon generating the DOM, because it doesn't take the CSS into consideration. But  since WordPress also adds `loading="lazy"` to the markup, the image isn't being loaded directly in most cases. So maybe there are chances to change this on beforehand?

There should be a better way than manually filling the sizes attribute. Does anyone have any tips?

Comment: WP has a filter `wp_get_attachment_image_attributes` you can use. https://andrewrminion.com/2018/01/wordpress-responsive-images-srcset-sizes-attributes/

Comment: You can also remove lazy loading if you want - `add_filter( 'wp_lazy_loading_enabled', '__return_false' );`

Comment: @disinfor I'm able to set the correct sizes myself, see the example that I posted in the opening post (the one with `echo wp_get_attachment_image()`. But I'm wondering if there is a better way then doing it manually.

Comment: Yes, that's why I shared the filter. Since you can take care of all your `sizes` attributes for several image sizes at once, rather than in the `wp_get_attachment_image`. Since you would have to set your image sizes every time doing what you are currently doing, you can use the filter and based on the image size name, you can do it all at once.

Comment: @disinfor I looked at the post and I thank you for the suggestion. I'm not quite sure if I can work with it. The problem with this is, it can't really be integrated in a reusable template-part. On a specific page a template-part can be used in a 2-column view on i.e. a viewport-width of 1400px, while on another page the same template-part is being used in a 5-column view in the same viewport. In that case the `sizes` attribute needs to be filled completely different. Well, there's always ways around that as well, but it's still a tough cookie.

Comment: Yeah, if you are using the same template part - but using different layouts, you will need to set it manually. Unless you are able to pass a variable to `get_template_part` (which you can as of the WP 5.5) - and then you can use that variable to trigger a conditional in `wp_get_attachment_image_attributes`. Good luck!

Comment: Yes, the way you described is part of what I did. I wrote a function to calculate the width of the image in the viewport, according to the number of columns it's supposed to fill for the 5 Bootstrap breakpoints, these numbers are passed to the function when calling `wp_get_attachment_image_attributes()`. Then I defined a default array with column settings in the template-part. And this array can be overwritten by defining a specific value upon calling `get_template_part()`. It's a lot less convenient then what I hoped for, but at least it works and it's kind of reusable for me.

Comment: If you want to remove the native lazy loading for an individual image loaded using `wp_get_attachment_image()`  you can pass `'loading'=>false` with the attributes array.

Comment: @ProxxiM Can you share your solution?